# Can't get image height, getting naturalHeight instead

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm writing a simple handler which shows image preview before upload. Here is my sample code:

```
function subscribeImageShower() {
    $('input[type="file"][data-image-show]')
        .each(function() {
            var $input = $(this);
            var $img = $($input.data('image-show'));
            var selectCallback = window[$input.data('image-selected')];
            var unselectCallback = window[$input.data('image-unselected')];

            $(this)
                .on('change reset',
                    function() {
                        if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
                            var reader = new FileReader();
                            reader.onload = function(event) {
                                $img.attr('src', event.target.result);
                                $img.show();

                                if (selectCallback) {
                                    $img.one('load', selectCallback);
                                }
                            };
                            reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
                        } else {
                            $img.removeAttr('src');
                            $img.hide();
                            if (unselectCallback) {
                                unselectCallback($img[0]);
                            }
                        }
                    });
        });
}
```

Markup:

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <div id="logoCanvasDiv">
        <img id="logoSampleImg" width="350" style="position: absolute;"/>
        <canvas id="logoCanvas" width="350" style="border: thick; position: absolute"></canvas>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="file" name="modelFile" data-image-show="#logoSampleImg" data-image-selected="onLogoSelected" data-image-unselected="onLogoUnselected"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="objectId" value="@Model.PageObject.Id" hidden />
    </div>
</div>
```

In select callback I want to get image width and height:

```
function onLogoSelected(event) {
   var img = event.target;
   alert('jQuery height = ' + $(img).height());
   alert('DOM height = ' + img.height);
}
```

For image with width `800x600` in following example I get `0` and `600` respectively.
But after sometime I get actual image size - `350x263`.

Why am I getting such invalid information? How can I get image size after it's loaded completly? I subscribed on `load` event, but it seems to be not working.

How to reproduce: select a file - it's loaded correctly. Unselect a file. Then select it again. Now `height` is invalid.

Comment: Try getComputedHeight(), that could be a solution.

Comment: @Feathercrown `getComputedStyle` is what I believe you're referring to.

Comment: Yeah, that. Thanks :3

Comment: Just a suggestion, but you can use `URL.createObjectURL(file)` instead of using the filereader

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan it's returning style, which is following in my case: `window.getComputedStyle($('#logoSampleImg')[0]).height = 
"auto"`,
`window.getComputedStyle($('#logoSampleImg')[0]).width =
"350px"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer, I didn't post the entire callback text, and here was a problem:

```
function onLogoSelected(event) {
    var img = event.target;
    console.log(img.height);
    $('#logoCanvasDiv')
        .css({
            'width': img.width,
            'height': img.height,
            'margin-bottom': 10,
            'position': 'relative'
        })
        .show();
};

function onLogoUnselected() {
    $('#logoCanvasDiv').hide();
};
```

parent div was hidden when image was loading, this is why it setted height to `0`.

Solution: just make sure all parent elements are visible atm you load the image.